# Mail App that doesn't group & dismiss all notifications

Tags: android, email, notification

So I am using the default mail client on my Android Oreo device.  It [dismisses all notifications when opening an app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191401/all-notifications-dismissed-when-opening-app).  I understand it would probably be impractical to change all apps, but might there be an android mail app that doesn't dismiss all notification for the app when opened?